# Adding mouse move event to change styling in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events, mouseevent, use-effect

While using React, I am trying to get the opacity of an image to change on the location of the mouse relative to the x-coordinate of the page. Need help with the code below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState }  from "react";
import "./style.css";

function Imaging() {

const [testOpacity, setOpacity] = useState("1")

const listenMoveEvent = () => {
window.clientX > 100
 ? setOpacity(".2")
 : setOpacity("1")
}

useEffect(() => {
window.addEventListener("nativeEvent",listenMoveEvent);
})

return (
<>
<img id="xOpacityImage" 
style={{opacity: testOpacity}}
src={require('../../assets/img/Sidewalk.png').default}
alt={"xOpacityImage"}/>
</>
);
}
export default Imaging;
```

Comment: What's the question? What did you get? What do you expect?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I am not sure what is wrong with my code. I am attempting to have an image change opacity to 0.2 whenever the mouse moves past x-coordinate "100" (will modify that after figuring out this react mouse event). What I am getting is nothing (the image does not change opacity). This code is not firing up.